# Loop Through Discord Message History In Channel And Delete

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to loop through message history of a particular Discord channel and delete all previous messages before sending new messages to the channel. I can't seem to figure this out and have searched EVERYWHERE to find a solution. My code below:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

async def my_background_task():
  channel = client.get_channel(999999999999999)
  history = await channel.history().flatten()
  await channel.delete_messages(history)
  
  # Loop and send messages to channel
  while not client.is_closed():
    await channel.send('Test')
        schedule.every(5).seconds.do(my_background_task)
    
# Loop event
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Running...')
    client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
```

When I go to run my code, I get the following error:

`repl process died unexpectedly: signal: killed`

Comment: Is your channel too large (are there too many messages)? The error message shows that you've run out of memory. Maybe trying to store all of the message history is taking up too much memory.

Comment: Don't use `schedule`, use `discord.ext.tasks` instead. Deleting every message is difficult, even if you use `channel.purge`. I would recommend simply "nuking" the channel. Delete it, and then make a new one with the same name, settings, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the channel.purge() methode instead. It Works fine for me. The only Problem is that it will be a bit laggy if there are too many messages in the channel.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

#deletes all messages in one particular channel
async def deleteAllMessages(deleted, channel):
    purge = len(await channel.purge(limit=100))
    if purge < 100:
        print(f"process finished\n{deleted+purge} messages were deleted.")
        return
    else: 
        await deleteAllMessages(deleted+100, channel)
        return

async def my_background_task():
    channel = client.get_channel(999999999999999)
    await deleteAllMessages(0, channel)
  
    #Loop and send messages to channel
    if not client.is_closed():
        await channel.send('Test')
            schedule.every(5).seconds.do(my_background_task)
    
# Loop event
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Running...')
    client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
```

I hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: Your `deleteAllMessages` will result in an infinite recursion if there are less than 100 messages in the channel. You keep trying to delete them, but there aren't any (forever).

Comment: it wont. If there are 65 messages left, the `channel.purge()` will delete them and return 65 as length. I tested it with my discord bot. And if there are none left it will just return 0

Comment: Oh wait, I misread it. That will be extremely slow however. You can't bulk delete messages more than 2 weeks old, so each one has to be deleted individually and you'll get hit by the ratelimits.